# Rails serve page directly from view file without merging into application.html.erb

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have some common HTML for most of the views (like headers and footers), so I put them in `application.html.erb` file.

Now, I have few pages whose HTML has nothing in common with others, so instead of changing `application.html.erb` and impacting all the pages, I want a way to load these few pages completely from the view file without involving `application.html.erb`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `render layout: false` at the end of your action or if you want to use it for every action in the controller, add `layout false` at the beginning of the controller.

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare layout false un the controller action like:

```
def action_name
...
    render layout: false
...
end
```

You can check render option in http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#options-for-render

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to render no layout or other layout.
By default is application.html.erb layout.

-In below code, no layout is called to any actions. Or specified layout is called to all actions.

```
class UserController < ApplicationController
  layout :false
  def action
    ..
  end
end
```

-In below code, only specific action layout is called and for other actions default layout is called.

```
class UserController < ApplicationController
  def action
    ..
    render layout :false
  end
end
```

Comment: You are duplicating the existing answers.

Comment: @Farooq I just clarify the coding and specify different ways to render layout

Comment: Your code snippets were actually wrong, just edited them.